# Multiuser Homebrew privileges

Tags: permissions, osx, homebrew, multiuser

I have two users on my Mac. Both are me, but one is work mode, the other is non-work mode. I have an ongoing issue with installing via homebrew.

```
$ brew install x
Error: Can't create update lock in /usr/local/var/homebrew/locks!
Fix permissions by running:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/homebrew
```

Of course, executing this suggested code solves the problem -- until I need to brew install using my other user, then I need to change ownership again. How can I set the permissions so that both users can install with homebrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about `homebrew` in particular, but in theory you could use `sudo` to install software.  Then files are accessed with `root` privileges, which may or may not be what you want.

---

In general though, if you want multiple unprivileged users to be able to write to the same location, it isn't the *owner* of that location that you want to change, but its *group*.  You could create a group called `homebrewers`:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Groups/homebrewers
```

You'll then want to find a group ID that doesn't exist.  For this I used:

```
dscl . -list /Groups                          \
| sed 's@^@/Groups/@'                         \
| ( while read grp;                           \
    do dscl . -read "${grp}" PrimaryGroupID;  \
    done )                                    \
| sort -snk 2
```

I found that the highest group number in use was 501, so 4200 was available.
So, I set the `PrimaryGroupID` to `4200` and the `Password` to `*` (unused).  Do not forget to set these!  If you do, your groups list will be corrupted and you will likely have to boot into single-user mode to correct it.

```
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/homebrewers PrimaryGroupID 4200
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/homebrewers Password '*'
```

Then add your two users to that group.  The example here uses shortnames (from `whoami`) of `user1` and `user2`:

```
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/homebrewers GroupMembership user1
sudo dscl . -append /Groups/homebrewers GroupMembership user2
```

Note that you may have to log out and log back in for these changes to take effect.

Finally, you'll want to change the directory's group to be `homebrewers` and its permissions to be group-writable:

```
chown -R :homebrewers /usr/local/var/homebrew
chmod -R g+w /usr/local/var/homebrew
```

If you want, you can even change the owner to `root` to no ill effects:

```
sudo chown -R root /usr/local/var/homebrew
```

All commands shown here were tested on Mac OS X 10.4.11 on a PowerBook G4.  Much has changed since the move to Intel, so the commands as shown may not work exactly as given on a newer release.  The underlying concepts will remain the same.

Comment: Congrats on holding on to such a relic of a machine. I noticed that you mentioned 10.4. Were you testing with Tigerbrew?

Comment: As I said, I don't know about homebrew, but I do understand UNIX permissions. I use the G4 because I don't like x86 as an architecture, and I use 10.4.11 because I never bought a copy of 10.5. At some point I did obtain an x86 machine, but I still prefer my SPARCs and PPCs. My 68k machines, while still functioning, are less useful than I'd like