# Homebrew multiuser on Monterey M1

Tags: macos, arm, homebrew

I am trying to setup a 2 user Homebrew configuration on my M1 Mac on Monterey. I have 2 accounts on the laptop: `bob` and `work`. `bob` will be the Homebrew owner, and `work` will access it via a sudo to `bob`.

Following [this article](https://www.codejam.info/2021/11/homebrew-multi-user.html), under sectiion "the good", I have installed homebrew into `bob` and have created a sudo alias in the `.zshrc` of `work`, my .zshrc contains

```
fpath+=("/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions")
alias brew='sudo -Hu bob brew'
```

However, when I run brew commands from `work` it is not working.

```
❯ brew
Password:
sudo: brew: command not found

~
❯ which brew
brew: aliased to sudo -Hu bob brew
```

These other articles were not helpful but linking here for completeness:

- [Multiuser Homebrew privileges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351513/multiuser-homebrew-privileges)
- [Configuring homebrew for multiple users on MacOs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/598733/configuring-homebrew-for-multiple-users-on-macos)

Comment: Does `work` also run the usual `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"` to set up the correct environment variables to be able to use `brew` at all?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @kusalananda for the tip.

This is now working with these commands at the top of my `.zshrc`

```
alias brew='sudo -Hu bob /opt/homebrew/bin/brew'
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
fpath+=("/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions")
```

Running commands

```
❯ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.

~
❯ brew services
Name       Status User File
postgresql none   bob
redis      none   bob
```

Comment: Running brew with sudo is bad: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad